# Why didn't Mohini recognise Rahu while distributing Amrita?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, samudra-manthan

During Samudra Manthana, Amrita was distributed to Devas by Mohini, who is an avatar of Lord Vishnu. However, the demon Rahu gets to drink Amrita by deceit. Surya and Chandra recognise Rahu and alert Mohini. The question is why didn't Mohini recognise Rahu? If She knew that Rahu is getting Amrita by deceit, why did She give it to him?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question..I have the same doubt on it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swami Prabhupada provides answer to this in his commentary on [ŚB 8.9.24](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/9/24/):

> Here one may ask why the Supreme Personality of Godhead could not detect Rāhu. The reason is that the **Lord wanted to show the effects of drinking nectar**.

In the commentary of next verse, he mentions

> Rāhu had been drinking nectar through his mouth, and before the nectar entered his body, his head was cut off. Thus Rāhu’s head remained alive whereas the body died. **This wonderful act performed by the Lord was meant to show that nectar is miraculous ambrosia**.

The same thing is mentioned in the book [Stowies
By Satsvarūpa Dāsa Gosvāmī: Stowie 24 (Page 83)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6NDbOGluRm8C&pg=PA81&dq=why+couldn%27t+the+Lord+detect+Rahu?&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit3_3HypnkAhWWaCsKHU34CCYQ6wEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=why%20couldn't%20the%20Lord%20detect%20Rahu%3F&f=false).

Comment: Please correct me if m wrong, Rahu's body didn't die. It is still alive and it's called "Ketu"(one of the nine graha). When his head cut-off, his head and body was alive and well. Head called "Rahu" and body called "Ketu". Netctar protected his whole body, not just head.

Comment: @Rishabh [SB 6.6.37](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/6/6/37/) recognise them as different entities..

Comment: This is new info for me. That's mean ketu has different story (not Mohini incident) of loosing his head (other story than smundra manthana)?